# Set Kendo UI Grid Page Index in the MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to set the page index for a kendo grid on the controller to avoid the client side paging. When using the client side paging to does not show any records besides that on the first page. When calling the data from the controller, I only return the 10 records that are required for the page. The data call includes Skip() and Take() functions to only return needed from the server instead of loading the whole grid.

**.cshtml**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Reckon.Service.Payroll.Data.DTO.EmployeeDto>()
        .Name("EmployeeGrid")
        .Columns(cols => 
        {
                cols.Bound(emp => emp.Id).Title("ID").Hidden();
                cols.Bound(emp => emp.EmployeeNumber).Title("Employee ID").Width(100);
                cols.Bound(emp => emp.IsPayRunReady).Title("Status").Width(10).ClientTemplate("<span title='This employee is #= IsPayRunReady ? '': 'not '#payrun ready.' class='#= IsPayRunReady ? 'okICN-small' : 'alertICN-small'#'>#= IsPayRunReady ? '': 'Not' # #= IsPayRunReady ? 'P':'p'#ayrun ready</span>");
                cols.Bound(emp => emp.FirstName).Title("First Name").Width(100);
                cols.Bound(emp => emp.LastName).Title("Last Name").Width(100);
                cols.Bound(emp => emp.DateOfBirth).Title("DOB").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").Width(100);
                cols.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.Action("EmployeeDetailEdit", "EmployeeDetail") + "/#=Id#'>Edit</a>").Width(50);
                cols.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.Action("EmployeeDetailRead", "EmployeeDetailRead") + "/#=Id#'>View</a>").Width(50);
                cols.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<a class='k-button xxx' tag='#=Id#'>Delete</a>").Width(50);
        })
            .Pageable(pageable => pageable.ButtonCount(5))
            .Sortable(sortable => sortable.AllowUnsort(false))
            .Filterable()
            .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
            .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
            .Navigatable()
            .Events(evt => evt.DataBound("afterGridLoaded"))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                    .Ajax()
                                    .Batch(true)
                                    .PageSize(10)
                                    .ServerOperation(false)
                                    .Model(model =>
                                    {
                                        model.Id(emp => emp.Id);
                                    })
                                    .Read(read => read.Action("EmployeeListPerPage", "EmployeeDetail"))
                                   )
      )
```

**.cs**

```
public ActionResult EmployeeListPerPage([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        Dispose();
        EmployeeListRequest empList = new EmployeeListRequest();
        empList.PageNum = request.Page;
        empList.PageSize = request.PageSize;
        //empList.OrderBy = null; //request.Sorts.Any() ? "EmployeeNumber" : request.Sorts[0].Member;

        var dataSource = _payrollService.GetEmployeeListPerPage(empList);
        var model = new EmployeeListModel(dataSource);

        DataSourceResult result = model.Employees.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        result.Total = dataSource.Total;            

        // Set the Page index here

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
    }
```

When using the client side paging, it sets the return data to the first page and then performs the client side paging returning no results.

Is it possible to be done? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For what reason do you not want to use Kendo's paging?

Comment: The kendo paging is client side and when the data is returned from the server-side it will only return the 10 records that was needed for the current page. The records are bind to the grid as the first 10 records and when you click for any other page besides the first page, it will not display any other records. That is the reason why  I don't want to use the kendo paging as I'm not returning all the data to the grid and only the data that is needed for the current selected page.

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to do this: `empList.PageNum = request.Page;` You're doing a lot of extra work there, essentially fighting what Kendo does automatically for you.  If you visit a page (via querystring), it will return the proper page for you.

Comment: This, **empList.PageNum = request.Page;**, is done because the function **GetEmployeeListPerPage** takes in a _EmployeeListRequest_ parameter only. Can you please give me an example?

Comment: Is your `GetEmployeeListPerPage()` method returning an `IQueryable<T>` and are you using Entity Framework or nHibernate?  It still seems like you're trying to fight Kendo. See Step 7 here: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-binding

Comment: I'm using entity framework. The whole goal was to use server side paging for the kendo grid and only pull back the needed data for the current page and not the entire grid on load.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Entity Framework, change your controller to this to let Kendo/EF take care of the paging (it will be server side):

```
public ActionResult EmployeeList([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var employees = from emp in dbContext.Employees
                    select emp;

    return Json(employees.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.
}
```

That's a rough example, but should be a starting point.

Comment: Hi @mmillican, I have tried the above way before but that would return the full dataset and the current table that I'm working with has more than 1 million records. Allowing the server to pull all those records for every server page or even once at the begin will cause alot of load on the server. That is why I'm to load only the current page details at a time.

Comment: @pchannon - it seems like something isn't correct with your EF then.  It should defer the execution and only pull back the results required for that page.